# Extract groups separated by a substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains groups separated by specific substrings. Something like:

```
FOO10 F10 O20  FOO20 F11 O11
```

I want to split it into groups while preserving the group identifier, i.e.

```
FOO10 F10 O20
FOO20 F11 O11
```

Is there a way to capture anything from the word FOO to the left boundary of the next FOO or end of the line?

Comment: Is your format always: `FOOx Fx Ox` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('FOO.*?(?=FOO|$)', "FOO10 F10 O20 FOO20 F11 O11" )
['FOO10 F10 O20 ', 'FOO20 F11 O11']
>>> map(str.strip, re.findall('FOO.*?(?=FOO|$)', "FOO10 F10 O20 FOO20 F11 O11" ))
['FOO10 F10 O20', 'FOO20 F11 O11']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = "FOO10 F10 O20  FOO20 F11 O11"
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"FOO(?:(?!\s*FOO).)*")
>>> regex.findall(s)
['FOO10 F10 O20', 'FOO20 F11 O11']
```

**Explanation:**

```
FOO         # Match FOO
(?:         # Start of non-capturing group:
 (?!\s*FOO) # Assert that we're not right before (whitespace) FOO
 .          # Match any character
)*          # Repeat as needed
```